# Подскажите плиз источники и ресурсы для React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мможете подсказать как и по каким источникам лучше учить React JS, если шарю немного   Java Script

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Учи по документации. Благо есть русский перевод. Так же читай статьи разные по React. И просто пиши код

Answer (score 0):

1. Почитайте про компоненты реакта
2. Жизненный цикл компонентов
3. Props и state

---

- Познакомьтесь с реактом на сайте [metanit](https://metanit.com/web/react/1.1.php)
- Изучите [документацию](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)
- Посмотрите канал [webDev](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE9ODjNIkOHrnSdkYWLfYhg/featured), там хороший курс по реакту

---

Напишите todo лист.

Удачи!